# Flake8 linter not highlighting errors in Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext3, pep8, flake8, linter

I have Sublime Text3 v3.2.1 Build 3207 installed on my Windows 10 PC. I have flake8 installed via pip command within conda environment. I have also installed the sublime flake8 linter and the python flake8 packages on sublime text.

The problem is, I am able to see the relevant linting errors in my files using the anaconda prompt (eg flake8 utils.py). However, the sublime linter isn't highlighting those errors in the same file in sublime text editor. I do, although, see flake8(erred) in the status bar of the text editor.

What might I be missing here?

Below are the settings for both the linters -
Flake8Lint settings:

`{
    "debug": false,
    "lint_on_save": true,
    "lint_on_load": false,
    "live_mode_lint_delay": 1000,
    "set_ruler_guide": false,
    "popup": true,
    "highlight": true,
    "highlight_type": "error",
    "highlight_color_critical": "#981600",
    "highlight_color_error": "#DA2000",
    "highlight_color_warning": "#EDBA00",
    "gutter_marks": "theme-simple",
    "report_on_success": false,
    "blink_gutter_marks_on_success": true,
    "use_flake8_global_config": true,
    "use_flake8_project_config": true,
    "python_interpreter": "auto",
    "builtins": [],
    "pyflakes": true,
    "pep8": true,
    "pydocstyle": true,
    "naming": true,
    "debugger": true,
    "import-order": false,
    "import-order-style": "cryptography",
    "complexity": -1,
    "pep8_max_line_length": 79,
    "select": [],
    "ignore": [],
    "ignore_files": []
}`

Sublime Linter Settings:

`{
    "debug": false,
    "delay": 0.1,
    "gutter_theme": "Default",
    "highlights.demote_while_editing": "none",
    "highlights.demote_scope": "",
    "highlights.time_to_idle": 1.5,
    "highlights.start_hidden": false,
    "kill_old_processes": false,
    "lint_mode": "background",
    "linters": {
        "linter_name": {
            "disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "executable": "<automatically set>",
            "env": {},
            "excludes": [],
            "filter_errors": [],
            "lint_mode": "manual",
            "selector": "",
            "styles": [
                {
                    "codes": [""]
                }
            ],
            "working_dir": "",
            "python": 3,
            "disable_if_not_dependency": false
        }
    },
    "no_column_highlights_line": false,
    "paths": {
        "linux": [],
        "osx": [],
        "windows": []
    },
    "show_hover_line_report": true,
    "show_hover_region_report": true,
    "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
    "show_panel_on_save": "never",
    "statusbar.counters_template": "({}|{})",
    "statusbar.messages_template": "{message}",`

```
"statusbar.show_active_linters": true,
"styles": [
    {
        "scope": "region.yellowish markup.warning.sublime_linter",

        "types": ["warning"]
    },
    {
        "priority": 1,
```

Cross/error.png"
            "icon": "dot",

```
        "mark_style": "outline",

        "scope": "region.redish markup.error.sublime_linter"
    }
],

"syntax_map": {
    "html (django)": "html",
    "html (rails)": "html",
    "html 5": "html",
    "javascript (babel)": "javascript",
    "magicpython": "python",
    "php": "html",
    "python django": "python",
    "pythonimproved": "python"
}
```

}

Comment: You can access the package settings via `Preferences > Package settings` tab on the menu item, choose your packge -> `Setting - defaults`

Comment: It's like the same problem for me now. Did you find any solution to this later? I'm trying to play with 'executable' and 'working_dir' settings. Couldn't make it work yet